# New TFS 2010 Features

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know where I can go to get a list of the new TFS 2010 features.

NOTE: I need **TFS** 2010 features. ***Not***  **Visual Studio** 2010.

My boss is wondering why not just upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 and not worry about updating TFS from 2008 to 2010.  (VS2010 is compatable with TFS 2008.)

Any input would be nice.

Comment: It's too bad so many 'answers' are just links instead of actual meaningful answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Channel 9 and MSDN:

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL52/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd441784.aspx#ALM

The [TFS Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/team_foundation/) also has some interesting content, but you have to sift through it.

Comment: +1 for the channel 9 link.  The MSDN link doesn't really go anywhere specific.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I fixed the MSDN link.

Comment: The msdn link seems to go to Visual Studio, not TFS

Answer (score 0):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/3/673B71D0-6D4F-4591-9940-D33DF9135487/DTL203_New_in_TFS_Bhatia.pptx