# TFS 2010 vs. 2008, bugfixes?

Tags: changelog

Is there a list somewhere of bugfixes or similar in TFS 2010 compared to 2008? We have some issues with 2008 and we're not sure if they're fixed in 2010 or not.

Specifically:

- TFS 2008 sometimes drop a changeset, the changes are present in the database but the changeset linking them together gets lost, next checkin someone does gets those changes attached to it
- TFS 2008 doesn't handle "get latest" well, we've just defaulted build machines to "get specific" with get everything + overwrite to ensure it really does in fact get the latest version of the files
- TFS 2008 is slow (probably because we have to strain it due to not doing Get Latest correctly)

Comment: Lasse - have you had your DBAs do a health check of your database? We've been using 2008 for a year and a half now (up to changeset 6,302,145) and haven't had problems like that.

Comment: I've never seen TFS 2008 drop a changeset; I work with TFS daily.

Comment: Nobody else has either. We got good help from Microsoft in looking into the problem but in the end we just patched then server, TFS and database to latest version and haven't had the problem since. We're upgrading to TFS 2010 in a month or two so we've just increased our awareness of what goes into TFS.

Comment: I'll have to agree.  There seems to be some major issues if you are experiencing some problems.  Feel free to contact me to troubleshoot:  http://www.edsquared.com

Comment: You might find an answer here in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610861/new-tfs-2010-features

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments it seems that your remaining big problem is "unreliable get latest".

You may find the following [perspective](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx) illuminating in many ways.

The short version of the story is that server workspaces are your only option in TFS 2008 and TFS 2010, are quite counterintuitive to use depending on what you exactly do, and that the TFS development team is acknowledging the situation and going to give you a choice in the next version after TFS 2010.