# Is there a definitive list of features in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

I don't want to know what the "new" features are, nor do I really want to know what capabilities are in Visual Studio (like modeling and such) that have nothing to do with TFS.

I have searched high and low and cannot seem to find the complete list of features anywhere.

Has anyone got a compiled list or can point me in the right direction on where to find such a list?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610861/new-tfs-2010-features

Comment: Yes I can easily get to a list of new features, which is why I specifically said I don't want to know what the "new" features are. I'm looking for something a little more comprehensive.

Comment: See my answer. That should get you started. If you want to deep dive into every feature, you have to search that feature individually (since they are so vast, its almost impossible to list them in one place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/features

Comment: OK, slight egg on my face here, because you would *think* the first place I would look is the product page, right? Having said that, this helped a little as it gave me the broad strokes of available features. I am still looking for something a little more detailed, but thanks for sharing the link!